# Why can I not subtract this inner cylinder?

Tags: boolean-modifier

I have created two cylinders, an outer and inner. The outer is a little wider, while the inner is a little taller.

I have tried the boolean tool multiple times to subtract the inner, but it is not working. I first select the outer, and then in the boolean modifier select the inner.

I have tried changing the inner body to wire just to see if it is subtracting, but no luck. I have also tried solidifying each body with a few mm of thickness without luck.

Any ideas greatly appreciated! File attached here: https://file.io/b3W2jsOWbOy7

and pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apart from the flipped normals you found, you said you want to subtract the inner from the outer - but in the screenshot your _Boolean_ modifier is set to subtract the outer from the inner... or at least it seems so, since the outliner says the selected object is "Circle", and in the viewport the outer cylinder is selected... the modifier is on "Circle.001" which supposedly is the inner cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I could have sworn I went to each object and clean->fix normals, but the normals were still off. For others interested, a good way to check your normals visually is going to "Face Orientation" option in object mode here:[image]

Red means you need to flip the normals (they are directed inside instead of outside). You can flip them here in the edit mode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The boolean is working. You need to switch off or delete the object you used to make the cut. Then you will see the hole you are looking for.